# I want output as [1,2,2,3,5,6] but its giving [0,1,2,2,3,5,6]. I do not know why this 0 is coming initially

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want output as [1,2,2,3,5,6] but its giving [0,1,2,2,3,5,6]. I do not know why this 0 is coming initially.

```js
var merge = function(nums1, nums2, ) {
  var nums3 = nums1.concat(nums2);
  nums3.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  nums3.filter((currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    if (currentValue === 0)
      nums3.splice(currentIndex, 1)
  })
  nums1 = nums3
  return nums1
};
console.log(merge([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], [2, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - show the input

Answer (score 2):

Update arr inside the filter function is a bad idea.

```js
// let me explain a little bit:
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', 'zero 1', 'zero 2', 'zero 3'];
arr.filter((x, index) => {
    if (x.includes('zero')) {
        console.log('before', arr);
        console.log(`arr=${arr},index=${index}`);
        arr.splice(index, 1); // <== error here, u cant 
        console.log('after', arr);
        console.log('============================');
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

try this:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0];
const b = [2, 5, 6];
const c = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0];

function mergeIgnoreZero(...params) {
    return params.flat().filter(num => num !== 0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log(mergeIgnoreZero(a, b, c)); // [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7]
```

Comment: Very elegant - this is even shorter and yet more versatile!

Answer (score 1):

The following will return the merged result while filtering out all "falsy" values. You can make it more targeted by using `.filter(v=>v!==0)` instead of `filter(v=>v)`:

```js
function mergeNonZero(nums1, nums2)
{
  return nums1.concat(nums2)
   .filter(v=>v)
   .sort((a, b) => a - b);
};
console.log(mergeNonZero([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], [2, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: Or just `const mergeNonZero = (nums1, nums2) => nums1.concat(nums2).filter(v => v).sort((a, b) => a - b);`

Comment: Yes, I agree, and that is exactly what my answer says. ;-) (if you disregard the fact that it is not using the arrow notation for the function definition).

Comment: I meant without the function and curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're misusing .filter(). Normally the idea is that you pass a function to filter which returns true or false for whether you want to keep that element. The function you passed to filter,

```
(currentValue, currentIndex) =>
{ 
    if(currentValue === 0) 
    nums3.splice(currentIndex, 1) 
}
```

, doesn't return anything, because you've got the function body in `{}` and no `return` statement. On top of that for some reason you are modifying nums3 inside the filter function, which is... confusing.